# Waiting in PowerShell for all child processes to finish

Tags: powershell, process, wait

I want to execute multiple external scripts in PowerShell simultaneously and then wait for all of them to finish before proceeding. Currently I am using 'start-process -NoNewWindow ...' commandlet that loops through all child processes but then terminates.

I have found many ways to wait for 1 process to finish (this is obviously trivial) but none of them seem to work as a solution for my problem.

Having an equivalent for [UNIX version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510922/waiting-for-all-child-processes-before-parent-resumes-execution-unix) in PowerShell would definitely be what I am looking for.

Comment: Unix give you far beter possibilities than Powershell : Python, bash, Perl.  Think more simple!

Comment: You said that you solved your problem with jobs? Would you be willing to share the solution?

Comment: Now you can run PowerShell on UNIX. https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell

Answer (score 36, accepted):

And don't forget about probably the most straight forward way to do this for mulitple processes - `Wait-Process` e.g.:

```
$procs = $(Start-Process Notepad.exe -PassThru; Start-Process Calc.exe -PassThru)
$procs | Wait-Process
```

Comment: +1 Keith. I completely missed wait-process. May be because I never used it :)

Comment: Yeah, it is a handy cmdlet from time to time. :-)

Comment: `Wait-Process` works flawlessly for multiple processes as well, however, I guess you cannot report real-time status information like number of currently running child processes and the only control you get is `Timeout` parameter.

Comment: +1 Remember the `-PassThru` parameter, otherwise `$procs` will be null!

Answer (score 9):

Did you check the background jobs feature in PowerShell v2?

```
$job = Start-Job -Name "Proc1" -ScriptBlock { Sleep 10000 }
Wait-Job -Job $job
```

Also, Start-Process has a parameter called -wait. When specified, Start-Process will wait for the child to exit.

```
Start-Process -FilePath calc.exe -Wait
```

Comment: -Wait switch is not really helpful when dealing with multiple processes. I managed to solve my problem using jobs, they're a great tool. Thank you!